# Convex hull partition of a set of points

Tags: runtime-analysis, computational-geometry

Given a set $S$ of $n$ points in $\mathbb R^2$, denote by $\mathrm{convb}(S)$ the boundary of the convex hull of $S$. Let
\begin{align*}
S_1 &= \mathrm{convb}(S)\\
S_{i+1} &= \mathrm{convb}\left(S \setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^i S_j\right).
\end{align*}

Now $S_1,\ldots$ forms a partition of $S$. Is there an $O(n\log n)$ time algorithm for computing this partition?

Comment: This partition is also known as the [convex layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_layers) of a point set. The Wikipedia article also claims that there is indeed such an algorithm.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. The name convex layers makes a lot of sense. I didn't think of it hence could not find the relevant articles.

Comment: It was published here: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/ConvexLayers.pdf